# How to print the description of testWidgets function in flutter integration test for debugging purpose?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

While running flutter integration test, in order to debug the test case from a huge logs file, i want to print the current test case name `(i.e Description of testWidgets)`.

For an ex: currently below test case name is: `TC_01 Test User OTP limits Exhausted`. And i want to save it to a variable in my test.

```
    testWidgets('TC_01 Test User OTP limits Exhausted', (tester) async {
      await app.main();
      expect(....);
      expect(....);

    });
```

Any helps highly appreciated.